# В странице магазина на woocommerce подменяется title страницы

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте! У меня появилась такая проблема :
Когда заходишь на страницу магазина открываются каталоги и происходит магия. В названии страницы задано " магазин " а в header title идет название последнего товара. Так же происходит в страницах категорий.Судя по всему он просто берет title не от title-page а уже откуда то из друго места, хуки по смене title на страницах магазина только убрали в h1 title. SEO плагины так же бессильны. На всех других страницах кроме магазина все хорошо выводиться из заголовка страницы. Как это можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось нужно было использовать для title `<?php wp_title(''); ?>` а не `get_the_title( $post );`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию у вас loop попал вовнутрь другого loop. Или забыли `wp_reset_query()`. Отключите ВСЕ плагины. Проверьте. Потом по одному включайте, попутно проверяя, не ломается ли тайтл. Если дело не в плагинах, активируйте дефолтную тему коммерца **storefront** или дефолтную тему самого WordPress. Если с ними все будет ровно, ищите трабл в своем коде